# Apple in-App Purchase would let me sell credits with 3rd service?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, payment, stripe-payments

I'm about to release an app working with Stripe to sell credits. The credits are used to be able to post premium messages to the app, users can choose if they wanna write a basic message or a premium one.

I've read that if it's a digital content, apple will make you sell it via in-App, right?

How can I still use Stripe to do so? If I integrate stripe with a webview apple would reject my app I think..

I think, I could sell credits via website (laptop) and then let the users use those credits with the app, right? But I shouldn't tell that this option is available inside the app but, what if I just set a webview with the url of my app and if they log in, they will be able to buy credits... would it be fine?

What Android says about that? is it legal to do that?

Comment: Do like Microsoft did with their Office 365 apps.

Comment: @user523234 Maybe you could provide a brief description of what Microsoft did to provide a starting point for further investigation.

Comment: I've seen that Office 365 is already paying the 30% to apple..

Comment: If I understand it correctly, users can buy their subscriptions both using IAP or from MS's web site...